# dlopen library path syntax

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I'm compiling the library for android (especially android M) and ı want to ask while I'm using `dlopen();` function, what is the correct syntax of library path?

Which one is correct?

**First one:**

```
libcameraHandle = ::dlopen("/system/lib/libseccameraadaptor.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

so the path is: **/system/lib/libseccameraadaptor.so**

or **Second one:**

```
libcameraHandle = ::dlopen("libseccameraadaptor.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

so the path is **libseccameraadaptor.so**

I also found something that can be good info for this specific subject but couldn't understand well [look into cool hacks/opengl section](http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=06.%20Thoughts&proj=04.%20Android%20M%20on%20Grouper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second syntax searches for `libseccameraadaptor.so` in standard paths and paths specified in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For a standard library like this which will be in `/system/lib` forever it does not really make much difference. For anything else, the second call is probly more robust if library is ever moved to different place.

Comment: Thanx man, i already solved the problem but didnt know the difference, i understand the difference now